# Comments on queries through MongoDB .Net driver?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Reading up on MongoDB performance troubleshooting I see that MongoDB supports appending comments on queries. We thought we might add our correlationid to queries so we can correlate which features result in slow queries and/or check whether when we discover slowness in a feature if we can spot some slowness in mongodb.

How can we add comments to queries and/or commands through the .net driver?

Answer (score 1):

> How can we add comments to queries and/or commands through the .net driver?

You can utilise [FindOptions.Comment](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.9/apidocs/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_FindOptionsBase_Comment.htm) to set a comment on a query or a command. For example:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<MyObject>("collectionName");

var filter = Builders<MyObject>.Filter.Eq("Name", "Foo");

FindOptions myFindOptions = new FindOptions();
myFindOptions.Comment = "THIS IS FEATURE XYZ"; 

var cursor = collection.Find<MyObject>(filter, myFindOptions).ToList();
```

Once you set the [database profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) i.e. via [db.setProfilingLevel()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/), you can then query the [(database).system.profile](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/system-collections/#%3Cdatabase%3E.system.profile) collection to find it. For example:

```
db.system.profile.find({
    ns:"dbName.collectionName", 
    "command.comment":"THIS IS FEATURE XYZ"
}); 

// Example result:
{   
    "op": "query",   
    "ns": "dbName.collectionName",   
    "command": {
         "find": "collectionName",
         "filter": {
             "Name": "Foo"
         },
         "comment": "THIS IS FROM FEATURE XYZ",
         "$db": "dbName",
         "lsid": {
              "id": UUID("6b722166-f50b-409c-85f0-2711633baff2"))
         }   
    },
 ....
}
```

The above .NET/C# code snippet is written using [MongoDB .NET/C# driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/) v2.9.3.